# Как следить за положением дефолтного скролла и в зависимости от него навешивать свойства на блок?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Необходимо навешивать свойства css на боковые границы блока (тени) в зависимости от положения горизонтального дефолтного скролла

пример: [image: scroll и тени]

---

Нашел решение, всем спасибо за подсказки!
https://jsbin.com/cutebuyine/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: Что вы пробовали сделать?

Comment: Вы имеете исходный код? пока ничего нет, просто даже представления не имею как отследить за положением дефолтного скролла. Может все-таки стоит использовать кастомный

Comment: Есть событие `onscroll`, в нем вы можете отследить положение скролла. Какой исходный код я должен иметь?

Comment: Нашёл решение, спасибо (буду смотреть на ширину блока и этим событием определять)
block.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) { console.log(block.scrollLeft)})

Answer (score 0):

Вот скрипт который определяет конец скролла, вы можете дописать в него необходимые изменения свойств тени.

```
   window.addEventListener("scroll", function (event) {
        if ((window.innerWidth + window.pageXOffset) >= document.body.offsetWidth) {
            console.log('End of the document')
        }
    });
```

Тут [песочница](https://jsfiddle.net/syntaxys/2vytbwoj/13/). Однако не очень понятно зачем вам нужен именно горизонтальный скролл.

Comment: Нашёл решение, спасибо (буду смотреть на ширину блока и этим событием определять) block.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) { console.log(block.scrollLeft)})